# Blisters on Fingers: Double Bass

Tags: health, double-bass, fingerstyle-bass

My band practiced for four hours tonight and I got a blister on my right middle finger, popped it (as I was playing), got another one, and got one on my index finger. We're performing twice tomorrow (I'm also playing with another group so three times, total) and I have the last lead in the last song and don't want to ruin it.

As it is, I'm not sure I'll be able to play as well as I normally can due to the blisters so my question is if there's some way I can get rid of them, make them stop hurting, etc.  by the time we play tomorrow.

Comment: Ah yes, the joy of playing music... When we played three gigs in a row and I already had blisters on both my index in middle finger before the last one, I would usually switch to playing as much as possible with the bow, or the ring finger, the index finger in _very_ angled position (so it's more the knuckle than the tips that get rubbed off), or the thumb. Strangely enough, there's also a kind of slap technique that puts considerably less strain on the fingers' skin than normal fingerstyle: not the usual pull-upwards&let-snap-down, rather a very brief hit from above&only slightly sidewards.

Comment: (My instrument is actually a 5-string cello though, not a proper double bass, so somewhat less torturous...)

Comment: I try to alternate fingers, rather than favour a couple. That way, if there's a finger problem, there's usually a finger or two that haven't been worn out. Mind you, that's on EBG, so not exactly the same. As lefta says, a slap technique is another option, and can alleviate wear and tear on certain well used digits.

Comment: I would also suggest that 4 hrs is too long for a rehearsal. In a lot of cases, everyone should go in having prepared their own parts. If you did the best part of that 4 hrs actually playing - and it seems that way with the blisters - that's a heck of a lot of songs/tunes. Or did the same ones get played over and over? There wouldn't be that much playing at a lot of gigs! Just a thought for next rehearsal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I play 5 string EBG. Sometimes if I get a new bass or change strings, I'll get blisters.

I use this stuff - it works pretty well. Protects the tender area but you still have flexibility to play.

Just spray it on and let it dry. It smarts a bit at first.
[***New-Skin® Liquid Spray Bandage***](http://www.newskinproducts.com/liquid-bandages/) .

Answer (score 0):

Bandage them up, or use a bandage substitute.  Then do what you have to do.  It'll hurt a bit.  You'll get through.

Comment: I'd rather play with cotton gloves than bandages!

Comment: OK, cotton gloves then.  Whatever gets you through it.  Won't be perfect, but you'll cope.   Or, if you really can't cope, dep out the gigs. No-one's THAT irreplacable.